# Preserving Greek letters on my PC

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, unicode, greek

How would convert this long table of vocabulary (one column of greek then one of english) in [this document](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0B8OcCV_2rJmLOGNmZDcxZmQtYTkzMS00YzBiLWE2NDgtNWQyMGNiNGEyYzQ2&hl=en_GB) into one excel spreadsheet where the Greek characters are preserved? Whenever I try to copy-paste I get results like this:

> ajgaqov", ajgaqhv, ajgaqovn

Comment: well, the document is a PDF and, as @AndrejaKo said, there is a font substitution... If there were no accents on Greek words in that doc, we would use Symbol font...

Comment: using PDF-XChange Viewer, selecting a greek word in that pdf and choosing text properties: Font: Graeca (Embedded Subset); Type: TrueType (CID); Encoding: Identity-H; Object Number: 36; Global Object ID: 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try one of these solutions. I think GreekTranscoder on MS Word can help you (I'm downloading to test it):

http://bibleandtech.blogspot.com/2010_05_01_archive.html

Comment: It's working. I'm just doing the conversion.

Comment: return to here to comment if it functioned :)

Comment: It worked and it worked perfectly. I pasted from PDF > Word (keeps it in a table) > Excel (where I removed the divider rows) > Word (to translate) > Excel. Thanks. There are a tiny number of problem rows but this software has loads of options to translate between all sorts of fonts. Final version here: https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsOcCV_2rJmLdHBZN3NwTi14M0RFN0tjcDE4MFV2YWc&hl=en_GB

Comment: if you use foxit pdf editor (i don't know other pdf editors...), select a Greek word and press "graphics keyboard", you can see an editor that uses that "special" font

Answer (score 5):

To me it looks like the original document is just doing something I've heard called font substitution.

Here is Serbia back in the 80s and 90s a quick way to get our unique characters was to just use a font which had our symbols for codes of Latin letters which were on keyboard position where our own letter would be. For example, let's take word `ужички`. On such systems, you'd type it as `u\i;ki` and use a font which displayed ж instead of \ and ч instead of ;. This is very easy to implement, because you don't actually use a different character set and when correctly displayed, here would be no difference. Unfortunately, this doesn't work well with internationalization and is a problem if you need several different character sets on a single computer.

As far as I know, the only solution for problems which came out of this is to use a program which will translate such text to proper Unicode text. The problem here is that you have a mix of Greek and Latin characters, so program can't just to dumb substitution. As far as I can see, there is no easy way to solve the problem.

You could try getting the document and running it through a proper OCR program which will detect letters and output in Unicode, but I haven't used OCR in quite some time, so I can't recommend one which will help. Also note that some OCR programs will only accept input from a scanner, so you need to be careful when picking OCR program, unless you want to print the whole document and them scan it.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Paste Special` and select `Unicode` instead of plain text.

Comment: I get the same effect when I do Paste Special "Text" or "Unicode Text"

Comment: Does the current font you are using support the Greek characters (`Character Map` will be able to show you this)

Comment: I believe so. I am using "Palatino Linotype"

Comment: I'd say it's probably the encoding that the Google Docs file is in, but I couldn't figure out a way to change that.  Wish I could be more help.